# Fedora 20: Can't install git

Tags: fedora, git

```
[root@8440p Downloads]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Cleaning repos: rpmfusion-free rpmfusion-free-updates rpmfusion-nonfree
              : rpmfusion-nonfree-updates updates
Cleaning up everything
[root@8440p Downloads]# yum install git
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0x7b: 11679/140709962184768
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0x7d: 11679/140709962184768
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.9.3-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.9.3-2.fc20 for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.9.3-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.9.3-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: perl-Git-1.9.3-2.fc20.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl(Error)
Error: Package: git-1.9.3-2.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl(Term::ReadKey)
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.9.3-2.fc20.noarch (updates)
           Requires: perl(Error)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest



[root@8440p Downloads]# yum install perl
Loaded plugins: langpacks
rpmfusion-free                                                  | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates                                          | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree                                               | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                       | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
updates/20/x86_64/metalink                                      |  27 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                         | 4.9 kB  00:00:00     
(1/2): updates/20/x86_64/group_gz                               | 395 kB  00:00:01     
(2/2): updates/20/x86_64/primary_db                             |  12 MB  00:00:20     
(1/10): rpmfusion-free-updates/20/x86_64/group_gz               | 1.6 kB  00:00:00     
(2/10): rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64/group_gz                       | 1.6 kB  00:00:00     
(3/10): rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64/group_gz            | 1.0 kB  00:00:00     
(4/10): rpmfusion-nonfree/20/x86_64/group_gz                    | 1.0 kB  00:00:00     
(5/10): rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64/primary_db                     | 445 kB  00:00:01     
(6/10): rpmfusion-free-updates/20/x86_64/primary_db             | 374 kB  00:00:01     
(7/10): rpmfusion-nonfree/20/x86_64/primary_db                  | 137 kB  00:00:02     
(8/10): rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64/primary_db          | 122 kB  00:00:02     
(9/10): updates/20/x86_64/updateinfo                            | 1.6 MB  00:00:05     
(10/10): updates/20/x86_64/pkgtags                              | 1.3 MB  00:00:04     
Package 4:perl-5.18.4-290.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And i tried to build git from source http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git :

```
[root@8440p Downloads]# cd git-2.1.3/
[root@8440p git-2.1.3]# make configure
    GEN configure
/bin/sh: autoconf: command not found
make: *** [configure] Error 127

[root@8440p git-2.1.3]# yum install autoconf
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autoconf.noarch 0:2.69-14.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: m4 >= 1.4.14 for package: autoconf-2.69-14.fc20.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: autoconf-2.69-14.fc20.noarch (updates)
           Requires: m4 >= 1.4.14
```

maybe it has something to do with the absence of repomd file? When i try to update from F20 to F21:

```
Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-install-21&arch=x86_64 error was 
No repomd file
```

Comment: Run `yum check` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: [root@8440p Downloads]# yum check
Loaded plugins: langpacks
check all